# Filter out the required stuff from an input

Tags: javascript

So I'm using webSpeechSysthesis to make something that can take inputs and give out results on it with the commands that I have ,  one command is the "solve" something like "solve √45" and it'll give the answer
I cant figure out how do I separate the √45 and use it to calculate , in Speech synthesis the string that is said is stored in a variable "text"

I tried using replace() and replace the solve with nothing so that I only have numbers and operators but I only get the ' ' , nothing after it

```js
Let word = "solve"
if(text.startsWith(word)){
   let final = word.replaceAll(/\bsolve\b/g,'')
   Console.log(final)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `let final = text.replaceAll(/\bsolve\b/g,'')` instead of `let final = word.replaceAll(/\bsolve\b/g,'')`.

```js
let text = "solve √45";
let word = "solve"; 
if(text.startsWith(word)) { 
   let final = text.replaceAll(/\bsolve\b/g,'');
   console.log(final);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For JavaScript that can be run in a browser, you can use a js/html/css snippet for better illustration of your code. Also, you should indent your code and insert proper line breaks between statements as your code will be read by the asker and proper line breaks can help them to understand your code better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if a word starts with solve, you can do this with regex as well using the `^` character. There is also no need to use the global flag with `replaceAll`.

```js
let word = "solve √45";

let final = word.replace(/^solve\b /g, "");

console.log(final);
```